How to plot the curve of the gravitational wave energy density giving the data of the strain versus frequency
I want to plot the curve of energy density ($\Omega$) of the gravitational waves versus frequency that are predicted by the Einstein telescope. But in the ET pages:
https://moscow.sci-hub.se/4444/781388f411114f6774c35ffd5f84c499/punturo2010.pdf?download=true
Or
https://www.et-gw.eu/index.php/etsensitivities#datafiles
Only the curves of the strain ($h$) exist. So how to get from the starin curves the energy density curves. Or how to relate $h$ by $\Omega$ . Also where are in ET pages the tables of the curves which can be imported after that to any program to plot that curves.
Any help is appreciated!
